# Is it ok to use a custom short domain for sharing third-party links?

Tags: seo, legal, url-shorteners, custom-short-url

I use a custom short domain which is a subdomain of my main domain, for sharing my website.

I would like to know if this is legally ok to use a custom short domain for sharing third-party links, also SEO-wise, could it have any negative effect on my website? because I am using my own subdomain to share third-party contents?

On my website and my social profiles, I regularly share direct links to other websites, without having a page or article about them on my website, which means I will not get much from those links, only my domain will get some attention.

Websites usually use their custom short domains ONLY for sharing contents of their main domain.

Comment: Please leave a comment and explain your reason when you down-vote, so I could improve my questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not a lawyer, but sharing links is something that happens all over the Internet, so it's hard to understand what is different about sharing links by using custom subdomains. I think the primary concern is whether or not you violating any copyrights. Summarizing content should not violate copyright, and typically even quoting the portions of the content, so long as it isn't the majority of the content, also doesn't violate copyright. I think you will be fine.